# Can't run Unit tests from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, junit

If I create a test class I can't run it from eclipse until I have run it via maven on the command line first. My project build path output folder is pointing to `project/target/classes`. And build automatically is checked in the eclipse.

Anyone know why eclipse doesn't create the classes automatically?

Comment: What happens if you *try* to run it in Eclipse? And is it definitely in a folder in the source path?

Comment: For a new test I get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`, if I run `mvm test` on the command line, then after run the test from Eclipse I don't get that Execption.

Comment: And is the source file definitely somewhere that Eclipse knows to be a source path?

Comment: Right click on project in `eclipse navigator > properties > Java Build Path`. On the Source tab the 'Allow output folders for source folders' is checked, and the default output folder is set to `myproject/target/classes` .

Comment: Writing the message above made it clear, that path is looking in the 'target/classes' directory but the tests are in `target/test-classes`

Comment: I've changed the output source folder directory to '/myproject/bin' but there are no binaries in there, how do you generate them in eclipse?

Comment: Do you have the m2e plugin installed?

Comment: "output source folder" doesn't make much sense - a source isn't an output. It's still very unclear how your project is configured to be honest.

Comment: @rlegendi yes I do have the m2e plugin installed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how the layout and build path of your project should look like.

**Layout**

[image]

**Build path**

[image]

Comment: Yes looks the same, it is as if when I create a new java class the file doesn't get created in `/myproject/target/classes`, I have to run `mvn test` first. So the question is, do I need to do something in eclipse to create/update class files in `/myproject/target/classes`. I already have the 'Allow output folders for source folders' checked.

Comment: If you set it up correctly i.e. as shown in my screen shots then Eclipse will compile Java classes to `target/classes`. JUnit test cases stored in `src/test/java` will be compiled to `target/test-classes`. If that ain't the case you need to verify the configuration is as shown.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Marcel said, someone who runs into the same problem should look for dependencies between projects within Eclipse.

I was working with project A, which depended on project B. Project A was built and run normally, except for the problem mentioned in this post (run a JUnit class test). After digging for a while, I noticed that Project B had a build error (a source folder went missing, who knows why) and Eclipse was not building the project B, which caused an error on project A.

As soon as I fixed the project B build error, the problem with JUnit class was solved.